Windows removable media event id 4656 not reporting all information
I am using PowerShell to generate a removable media report. I have all the advanced auditing setup and it is working as expected except for one item I can't figure out.
I have a thumb drive plugged in, then I create a new folder. When I gather 4656 (and 4663) events, there is a 4656 event generated for the "New Folder", however, the object name does not contain the  name of the actual folder created, it simply states "New Folder". I am looking for the actual folder created. Here is a sample of what is returned in the event for the Object Created:
    Object Name:        \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Temp\New folder

There are no events generated that contain that actual folder name (that I can find), they simply state "New Folder". Is there another event I need to correlate this with? I have converted the returned events to XML and still cant find the actual folder name anywhere. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

I'm not aware of any setting to make the event log service render the volume label in the log entry, but you can translate the object path by resolving the volume label associated with partition X, where X is the number following \Device\HarddiskVolume:
Note: the sample code below uses -replace '...', {...} syntax introduced in PowerShell 6.1 - for PowerShell 5.1 and older, see alternative syntax at the bottom of this answer
$objectNameData = $eventXml.SelectSingleNode('//Event/EventData/Data[@Name="ObjectName"]')

# yields "\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Temp\New Folder"
$objectNameData.InnerText 

# yields "C:\Temp\New Folder"
$objectNameData.InnerText -replace '^\\Device\\HarddiskVolume(\d+)\\',{
    (Get-Partition -PartitionNumber $_.Groups[1].Value).AccessPaths.Where({$_ -like '?:\*'}, 'First')[0]
}

To avoid repeatedly querying WMI for the same partition over and over again, use a hashtable to cache already-resolved paths:
$volumeLabelCache = @{}

foreach ($eventXml in $events) {
  $objectPath = $eventXml.SelectSingleNode('//Event/EventData/Data[@Name="ObjectName"]').InnerText 
  $resolvedPath = $objectPath -replace '^\\Device\\HarddiskVolume(\d+)\\',{
    $partitionID = $_.Groups[1].Value
    if (-not $volumeLabelCache.Contains($partitionID)) {
      # cache volume label so we don't need to query the same partition id again
      $volumeLabelCache[$partitionID] = (Get-Partition -PartitionNumber $partitionID).AccessPaths.Where({$_ -like '?:\*'}, 'First')[0]
      if (-not $volumeLabelCache[$partitionID]){
        # looks like we failed to resolve mount point from partition id, return original path
        return $_.Value
      }
    }

    # ... otherwise replace partition part of the object path with volume label 
    return $volumeLabelCache[$partitionID]
  }

  Write-Host "Resolved path '$resolvedPath' from '$objectPath'"
}


For PowerShell versions older than 6.1, you can call [regex]::Replace directly to get access to inline callbacks:
'input' -replace 'pattern', { substitution code <# over $_ #> }
# becomes
[regex]::Replace('input', 'pattern', {param($m) substitution code <# over $m #> })

Which, with the sample code above, would be something like this:
  [regex]::Replace($objectPath, '^\\Device\\HarddiskVolume(\d+)\\', {
    param($m)
    $partitionID = $m.Groups[1].Value
    if (-not $volumeLabelCache.Contains($partitionID)) {
      # cache volume label so we don't need to query the same partition id again
      $volumeLabelCache[$partitionID] = (Get-Partition -PartitionNumber $partitionID).AccessPaths.Where({$_ -like '?:\*'}, 'First')[0]
      if (-not $volumeLabelCache[$partitionID]){
        # looks like we failed to resolve mount point from partition id, return original path
        return $m.Value
      }
    }

    # ... otherwise replace partition part of the object path with volume label 
    return $volumeLabelCache[$partitionID]
  }


"I'm not aware of any setting to make the event log service render the volume label in the log entry," .. I guess I was not clear on my issue. I am not after the Volume Label. I am after the actual name of the folder created. The log entry only states "New Folder" for any folder created when in fact, the folder name created is "Testing123". ObjectName never seems to contain the actual name of the folder created. Sorry for not being more clear.

I did get this figured. In the Windows Advanced Audit Policy, aside from auditing Removable Storage, I also needed to audit "File System" which is not ideal, but I do now get the actual folder created. For others attempting to audit removable storage, you also need to following registry setting set to 1.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Storage\HotplugSecureOpen

This setting also seems to require a reboot.
